# Asp.Net Web User Control Extension

Tags: asp.net, controls

I have a Web User Control. I want to use this control in other web applications, I dont want to expose the code of my web user control. If modification is required in web user control it can be extended in respective web application.

Is it possible to extend web user control.
Any other alternative to this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that you cannont change in a webpart if you do not have the code.

There are a few approaches that you could try:

- Use [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mef)
- Try creating a new User Control and inheriting from the existing (this only inherits the code behide)